# inaccurate and strange cufflinks plot

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly for the first time and when I try to plot a stock dataframe, the plot is really weird:

[image]

Here is my dataframe:

```
             AAPL       AMZN
Date        
2008-12-31  10.681297   51.279999
2009-02-01  11.357091   54.360001
2009-05-01  11.836406   54.060001
2009-06-01  11.641174   57.360001
2009-07-01  11.389630   56.200001
```

code:

```
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

stocks['AAPL'].iplot()
```

My dataframe info

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2657 entries, 2008-12-31 to 2019-07-23
Data columns (total 2 columns):
AMZN    2657 non-null float64
AAPL    2657 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 62.3 KB
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are trying to plot on one column, which is a Series. You can try plotting whole DataFrame

What I have tried so far,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=200, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 200 entries, 2000-01-01 to 2000-07-18
Data columns (total 3 columns):
0    200 non-null float64
1    200 non-null float64
2    200 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 6.2 KB
```

What our dataframe looks like

```
df.head()
```

Output

```
               0           1           2
date            
2000-01-01  0.537956    0.575147    0.146626
2000-01-02  0.504606    0.309531    0.715763
2000-01-03  0.517008    0.591016    0.227111
2000-01-04  0.088941    0.702333    0.975861
2000-01-05  0.956740    0.627588    0.249751
```

and then the plot

```
df.iplot()
```

[image]

Comment: still doesn't work, plot the same wired looking chart.